# File storage link in Laravel

Tags: laravel, storage, laravel-artisan, file-storage

I use:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

After that i can access my file in public/storage

But when I add file like this:

```
request()->image->store('public/storage/foto');
```

or

```
request()->image->store('storage/foto');
```

or

```
request()->image->store('foto');
```

That put my file in storage/uploads directory and I don't have access to this files from browser. what did I do wrong? Maybe I skip some important settings?

Comment: [Filesystem](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem) read official documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure that the file is stored on your public disk in order for it to be accessible from a browser. You can specify the disk in the `store` method by adding it as a second parameter, e.g. `request()->image->store('foto', 'public');`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
   $request->file('image')->storeAs('public/images',$image_name);
```